# How to sort the rows of an csv file?

Tags: python, string, list, csv, sorting

Im trying to sort the rows of my csv file.

**This is my code:**

```
import os
import csv

my_path = r'c:\data\FF\Desktop\my_files\Zipped' 

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:
            if len(row) > 9:
                if row[9] == '3086':
                    print(row[25] + '-----'  + sorted(row[0]))
```

**This is my output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\data\FF\Desktop\Python\\untitled2.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(row[25] +  sorted(row[0]))

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: The result of sorted() is a list, string + list is illegal.

Comment: you issue is here `sorted(row[0])`, if you do sorted on a string you will get a list back. it is very unclear what you are trying to do, please explain what sort of sorting you mean.

Comment: You can rewrite the last line as `str(sorted(row[0]))`, then it should work

Comment: assuming `row[0]` is a `str`, I doubt you really want to sort individual chars of that string

Comment: Im trying to sort the values of `row[0]`

Comment: Can you add an example input and the expected output?

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your question to show a few sample rows of data